# How to use GPU in Docker to retrain an object detection model?

Tags: docker, tensorflow, ubuntu, google-coral

I've been following [this](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/retrain-detection/#set-up-the-docker-container) tutorial from google coral on retraining an object detection model in docker, and it explicitly states that this is for CPU training only, which is very slow.

Is there an easy way to port this docker container to utilize the GPU (nvidia GTX 1080). I have installed nvidia-docker2, and successfully gotten my gpu passed into other containers, and as far as I know, also this one, using the `--gpus all` tag. The `nvidia-smi` command works from within my container, so I am almost certain that my GPU has been passed through successfully, however it is not used when training the model.

CUDA version is 11.4 according to nvidia-smi, both inside and outside of the container, and I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What is the image name & tag you are using for training?

Comment: my image names are image1.jpg -> image2000.jpg with a few missing (but are also missing in csv and .tfrecord), labels are stored in a .csv and I encoded the data into a .tfrecord file. Headers are name, width, height, class (there is only 1 class: "ct"), xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax. I originally created a csv with headers TEST/TRAIN/VALIDATE, filename, class, TL, TR, BR, BL - each represented as a normalised pair of x and y values as it was designed for tflite model maker, but the inference on my coral dev board was very slow. Unsure exactly what you mean by tag? Assumed it was annotation.

Comment: CSV to .tfrecord is [here](https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py)

Comment: I meant docker image :)

Comment: Ah, sorry. [Link](https://github.com/google-coral/tutorials/tree/master/docker/object_detection) to the github Dockerfile. Thanks.

Comment: `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5` is cpu only image, you should use`tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5-gpu` to use CUDA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering myself to close the question as I see no way to do it on a comment, solution was a comment from sebastian-sz:

"tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5 is cpu only image, you should use tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5-gpu to use CUDA. – sebastian-sz
Jan 21 at 14:36"

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the solution provided here with Docker https://github.com/google-coral/tutorials/issues/5#issuecomment-821860067 or use the GPU based colab tutorial from google-coral tutorials (https://github.com/google-coral/tutorials) to retrain an object detection model

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).